Deriving inequality (8.9) from (8.8), in Iwaniec–Kowalski “Analytic Number Theory”
I am working through the problem presented in Chapter 8 of Iwaniec and Kowalski’s Analytic Number Theory (specifically inequalities (8.8) and (8.9)) and I am struggling with the transition between these two inequalities.
Inequality (8.8) is given as
$$
|S_f(N)|^2 \leq N + \sum_{l=1}^{N-1} \min \left(2N, \left\| {2\alpha l} \right\|^{-1} \right),
$$
where $\|x\|=\operatorname{dist}(x,\mathbb Z)=\bigl|x-\lfloor x+0.5\rfloor\bigr|$, and inequality (8.9) is
$$
|S_f(N)| \leq 2\sqrt{\alpha}N + \frac{1}{\sqrt{\alpha}} \log\left( \frac{1}{\alpha} \right),
$$
where $ S_f(N)=\sum_{n=1}^{N-1}e^{\alpha n^2+\beta n}$, and $ \alpha$ and $\beta $ are positive constants such that $0<\alpha\le1/2$.
My Attempt
To bound $ |S_f(N)|^2 $, I started with the upper bound in (8.8) and tried to refine it step by step. Here is my attempt:

By expanding the summation in (8.8), I can write
$$
|S_f(N)|^2 \leq N + \sum_{l=1}^{N-1} \min\left(2N, \left\| 2\alpha l \right\|^{-1}\right).
$$

Using the relationship between fractional parts and integration, I approximated the inner terms:
$$
\sum_{l=1}^{N-1} \min\left(2N, \left\| 2\alpha l \right\|^{-1}\right) \leq \sum_{k=1}^{2\alpha N + 1} \Bigl(\sum_{n \in \left(\frac{k-1}{2\alpha}, \frac{k}{2\alpha}\right]} \frac{1}{2\alpha n} + 2N\Bigr).
$$

Simplifying further and introducing integrals,
$$
\leq N + (2\alpha N + 1) \left(\frac{1}{2\alpha} \int_{1}^{1/(2\alpha)} \frac{1}{x} \, dx + 2N \right).
$$

Evaluating the integral and collecting terms:
$$
\leq 3N + N\log\left(\frac{1}{\alpha}\right) + 4\alpha N^2 + \frac{\log(1/\alpha)}{2\alpha}.
$$

Since
$$
3N \cdot (1 - \log(1/\alpha)) \leq \frac{1}{\alpha} \log(1/\alpha) \left(\log(1/\alpha) - 0{.}5\right), \quad \text{for } 0 < \alpha \le 1/e,
$$
it follows that
$$
\frac{1}{2\alpha} \log(1/\alpha) + 3N \leq 3N \log(1/\alpha) + \frac{1}{\alpha} \left(\log(1/\alpha)\right)^2.
$$
Thus,
$$
 3N + N\log\left(\frac{1}{\alpha}\right) + 4\alpha N^2 + \frac{\log(1/\alpha)}{2\alpha}\leq \left(2\sqrt{\alpha}N + \frac{1}{\sqrt{\alpha}} \log\left( \frac{1}{\alpha} \right)\right)^2.
$$

When $1/e < \alpha \le 0.5$ I use the trivial sum


Is my try correct?

Related: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/483289/clarification-and-proof-of-inequality-8-11-in-analytic-number-theory-by-iwanie

It would be better to make your post self-contained, with all the relevant definitions present, and with a complete description of (or a link to) the book in question.

Please do not include links to pirated or otherwise inappropriately obtained content. If you want to clarify which book you are referring to, you can link the publisher's page.

I don’t why you changed my edit, but the book clearly says “distance to the nearest integer”. The integer nearest to $x$ is not $\lfloor x\rfloor$, but $\lfloor x+1/2\rfloor$. For example, the distance of 0.99 to the nearest integer is 0.01, not 0.99.

@EmilJeřábek thanks you are correct
