Literature about techniques of estimation of exponential sums
In mathematics there have been developed a lot of techniques connected with estimation of various exponential sums. However, I did not succeed in finding the literature(in English) which tells in detail about the celebrated methods for estimation of exponential sums. The only good book I found was "Van der Corput's Method of Exponential Sums" by S. W. Graham and G. Kolesnik.
Could you please suggest me great literature(in English) in which I can read about other methods of estimation of exponential sums. For instance, about Vinogradov's or Weyl's method.
Thank you in advance!

If you're looking for excellent resources in English that delve into methods for estimating exponential sums, here are some recommendations that might be helpful:

"Explicit Sub-Weyl Bound for the Riemann Zeta Function" by Dhir Patel (Thesis) https://www.proquest.com/openview/6e4dac9a2b709c4af704435427676959/1?pq-origsite=gscholar&cbl=18750&diss=y
This thesis explores advanced bounds for the Riemann zeta function using sub-Weyl methods. It offers detailed insights into how exponential sums play a role in such estimates.

"Exponential Sums and Their Applications" by N. M. Korobov
https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-94-015-8032-8
A classic reference that covers various techniques and applications of exponential sums, including methods related to number theory and beyond.

"Explicit Bounds on ζ(s) in the Critical Strip and a Zero-Free Region" by A. Yang


https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022247X24000453
This work provides explicit bounds for the zeta function and discusses exponential sums within the context of analytic number theory, focusing on applications to zero-free regions.

"On Kuzmin–Landau Lemma" by J. Arias de Reyna
https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2020arXiv200205982A/abstract
This paper presents a deep analysis of the Kuzmin–Landau lemma, offering refined bounds and insights into its connection with exponential sums.

"The Hardy-Littlewood Method" by R.C.Vaughan
https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/hardylittlewood-method/5B45E102D5AFAD6FADDD66E4B510E7FA
This foundational text discusses a broad range of topics, including exponential sums, their estimations, and their role in analytic number theory.

"Analytic Number Theory" by Henryk Iwaniec and Emmanuel Kowalski
https://bookstore.ams.org/view?ProductCode=COLL/53
This comprehensive book provides a detailed overview of analytic number theory, including methods for estimating exponential sums, with a focus on techniques like Weyl's method and their applications in modern research.

"Explicit Estimates for the Riemann Zeta Function" by Yuanyou F. Cheng and Sidney W. Graham
https://www.jstor.org/stable/44239029
This paper provides explicit estimates for the Riemann zeta function, detailing techniques closely tied to exponential sums and their applications.

"An Improved Explicit Estimate for ζ(1/2 + it)" by Ghaith A. Hiary, Dhir Patel, and Andrew Yang
https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022314X23001920
This work refines previous explicit estimates for the Riemann zeta function on the critical line, incorporating modern methods that rely heavily on the analysis of exponential sums.


If you have difficulty understanding any of these resources, I’d be happy to help! I’m really interested in these topics and would enjoy discussing them further.

The answer would be more useful, and more reliable, if references for these items were given. For instance, who are the authors of item 5, and when was this "foundational text" written?

likely AI generated, as discussed at https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/6105/11260

@YemonChoi  Thank you for pointing that out! I've updated my answer to include links . I hope this makes the information more useful and reliable. Please let me know if there’s anything else I can clarify!

@CarloBeenakker Thank you for your feedback! I’ve updated my answer to include links and detailed references for each resource to make it more useful and reliable.
I’d also like to clarify that this is definitely my own writing. In fact, I posted a question https://mathoverflow.net/questions/483348/deriving-inequality-8-9-from-8-8-in-iwaniec-kowalski-analytic-number-theor
about this topic when I was reading Analytic Number Theory by Henryk Iwaniec and Emmanuel Kowalski. I’m deeply interested in this field and happy to share what I’ve learned.
